# Function not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, filter

I have created a search function that operates on a JavaScript filter function as follows:

```
result = machinePrinters.filter (search, query);
```

Search function follows:

```
function search(user) {
    return Object.keys(this).every((key) => user[key] === this[key]);
}
```

It works find in Chrome, however in IE 11 I get an error on the => symbol. The error is:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

I tried this and id did not work.

```
function search(user) {
    return Object.keys(this).every(function (key) { return user[key] === this[key]; });
}
```

Comment: _"I tried this and id did not work."_: "It did not work" is not a useful problem description. What happened? What should've happened? Are you getting any errors on that last code block?

Comment: Internet explorer 11 present many trouble, you should invite your user to use Edge, Chrome, Firefox and much more accomplished graphic web browser ... Maybe you could also try your code in text web browser like elinks and Emacs w3m ;-)

Comment: _"Maybe you could also try your code in text web browser like elinks and Emacs w3m "_ You're kidding, right, @aurelien?

Comment: @aurelien IE11 is fine if you know how to do stuff. This is part of the craft.

Comment: oh ok @dfsq I do not know it was possible. I got that trouble with dashing/smashing stuff

Comment: @Cerbrus no I do not kidding, text web browser are great tools when you works out of X ... and I works out of X most of time. (I do not think to be the only one on all the planet to works like that.)

Comment: _"works out of X"_... what? What's X?

Comment: @Cerbrus he's gon give it to ya

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your function to use non-arrow function expression then you need to make sure the scope is still points to the same context:

```
function search(user) {
    return Object.keys(this).every(function (key) { 
        return user[key] === this[key];
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) above we make sure that event callback function will be invoked in context the `search` function is being run in, same as it was before with arrow function (in your case it looks like it's `machinePrinters` object).

Comment: Thank you.dfsq.  That fixed the problem.